# Text editor tool for a NLP project

Tags: reactjs, nlp

I'm trying to build a text editor in react for a NLP project. I got a set of rules that can be placed on each word and some rules can be applied between words or phrases.

Right now I'm simply splitting the string on " " and then add to each word a rule or flag. I also added the option to select words, from a dropdown, and then insert a rule between the two selected sections.

I want to be able to select two words or phrases in the text itself and then add a rule between them - and the same when highlighting words in the text. Is there any library that can help me?

Thanks!

highlight words -> add rules from a dropdown -> apply to text